# Totalling 2 column in 1 table where the information is drawn from 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the 1st table (`tblProduct`) which contains 6 columns.

```
ProdID, BrandName, ProdType, Manuf, ProdDescript, Price
```

This table allocates a price to a product.

The 2nd table (`tblTransaction`) which has 5 columns.

```
TransID, TransDate, ClientID, ProdID, Quantity
```

This table has all the items sold and how many of each.

The 3rd table (`tblTransaction Query`) which has 4 columns

```
TransID, Quantity, ProdID, Price
```

This one was made to correlate the information in the first 2 tables so that there was a price next to the correct Product.

```
 SELECT tblTransaction.TransID, Quantity, tblProduct.ProdID, Price
 FROM tblTransaction, tblProduct
 WHERE tblTransaction.ProdID =  tblProduct.ProdID;
```

The 4th table (`tblProduct Query`) which has 2 columns

```
ProdID, Total_Quantity
```

It is what I made to show the total number of each product sold.
I want a 3rd column to show the total price of each item X quantity sold.
So the total of all of each product ( if that makes sense).

```
 SELECT ProdID, SUM(Quantity) AS Total_Quantity
 FROM tblTransaction AS Query
 GROUP BY ProdID;
```

I can provide the DB file and screen shots if that will help.
I am new to SQL so please bear with me.

I am currently doing SQL in Microsoft Access. It says at the top Database (Access 2000 file format)

Comment: It looks to me like Table 3 and Table 4 are not tables. It looks like they are queries. Are Table 1 and 2 real tables, or what?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct. 1 and 2 are the tables with the information in. 3 and 4 are queries. If 3 and 4 can be done in 1 query, that would be great.

Comment: Since the queries have a different number of columns with different data types they cannot be combined. Wait 5 for total price..

Comment: thanks, when I run this , it gives me a popup window That says "Enter Parameter Value" In the window it says Price and there is a space to enter something. I dont want to enter something, I want it to give me the total. If I click on ok, it puts the new column in but it is blank.

Comment: OK. I got confused about what was a table and what was a query. I'll adjust the query in a minute, but it'll be a bit more complex!

Comment: Cool, now I get an error message saying," The specified field'ProdID' could refer to more than one table listed int eh FROM clause of your SQL statement."

Comment: Ah yes, put p. in front of ProdID in the group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT p.ProdID, SUM(t.Quantity) AS Total_Quantity, sum(t.Quantity * p.Price) as total_value
 FROM tblTransaction AS t
 inner join tblProduct p on p.ProdID = t.ProdID
 GROUP BY ProdID;
```

Note that this is getting total value, not price. If you want average price, just add another column to the select:

```
AVG(Price)
```

Cheers -

(Amended post table/query confusion)